# In Jongo, how to find multiple documents from Mongodb by a list of IDs

Tags: mongodb, jongo

In mongodb, I can do this by the following query:

```js
find(
    { _id : { $in : [ ObjectId('5275c6721a88939923c3ea54'), ObjectId('5275c6721a88939923c3ea55'), ObjectId('5275c6721a88939923c3ea56'), ObjectId('5275c6721a88939923c3ea57'), ObjectId('5275c6721a88939923c3ea58') ] } }
)
```

But how can we do the same using Jongo code?

I know we can find one document via:

```js
db.getCollection("mongoEg").findOne(Oid.withOid("5194d46bdda2de09c656b64b")).as(MongoTest.class);
```

But how to get more than one documents in one query via Jongo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see two options to achieve a find on multiple ids:

```js
// 1. find with an array of ids
ObjectId[] ids = {id, id, id};
collection.find("{_id:{$in:#}}", ids).as(Friend.class);

// 2.find a list of ids
collection.find("{_id:{$in:[#, #, #]}}", id, id, id).as(Friend.class);
```

`findOne` offers a convenience method with an `ObjectId` and, if you use an annotated `String` instead of an `ObjectId`, the `Oid.withOid` method transforms your `String` into an `ObjectId`.

But, in the end, this convenience method input is transformed into a regular stringified query. So if the convenience don't fit your need, try a query instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still confused about the ObjectId class. Is it org.jongo.marshall.jackson.oid.ObjectId or org.bson.types.ObjectId? How can I convert a string (mongodb _id), like "5275c6721a88939923c3ea5c" to and ObjectId instance?

Comment: `ObjectId` is the type used by the MongoDB driver to manipulate Mongo `_id`. Jongo introduces an annotation, `@ObjectId`, to manipulate Mongo `_id` as `String`. Looking at the [Jongo documentation mapping section](http://jongo.org/#mapping) will give you a good idea of this. You can create an `ObjectId` out of a `String` with `new ObjectId(String)`, but you can avoid this in many cases.