# Too many parameters error on the following $in query

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, jongo

I'm using jongo API - `org.jongo.MongoCollection` is the class.

I have list of object ids and converted the same as `ObjectId[]` and trying to query as follows

```
collection.find("{_id:{$in:#}}", ids).as(Employee.class);

The query throws the exception - "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too      
many parameters passed to query: {"_id":{"$in":#}}"
```

The query doesn't work as specified in the URL [In Jongo, how to find multiple documents from Mongodb by a list of IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300100/in-jongo-how-to-find-multiple-documents-from-mongodb-by-a-list-of-ids)

Any suggestion on how to resolve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with a `List` as shown on the [docs](http://jongo.org/#query-templating):

```
List<String> ages = Lists.newArrayList(22, 63);
friends.find("{age: {$in:#}}", ages); //→ will produce {age: {$in:[22,63]}}
```

For example the following snippet I crafted quick & dirty right now worked for me (I use older verbose syntax as I am currently on such a system ...)

```
List<ObjectId> ids = new ArrayList<ObjectId>();
ids.add(new ObjectId("57bc7ec7b8283b457ae4ef01"));
ids.add(new ObjectId("57bc7ec7b8283b457ae4ef02"));
ids.add(new ObjectId("57bc7ec7b8283b457ae4ef03"));
int count = friends.find("{ _id: { $in: # } }", ids).as(Friend.class).count();
```

Comment: This doesn't work as collection.find returns MongoCursor and throwing cast exception. however the following works fine. How to covert MongoCursor to user defined List. i'm using the following                           List<T> collectionsAsList = new ArrayList<T>();
        MongoCursor<T> cursorCollection = collection.find("{ _id: { $in: # } }", ids).as(Friends.class);
        while (cursorCollection.hasNext()) {
            collectionsAsList.add(cursorCollection.next());
        }

Comment: It does work but you have to have a suitable `Friend` class of course - but that was also not the topic of your question but it was the way how to pass the list of IDs and that's the question if that works for you or not

Comment: That's worked fine and thanks a lot. I had the suitable class but does it type cast properly as it currently throws compilation error. is it possible to put a code snippet here?